# Postgres: return multiple tables as a JSON hash

Tags: postgresql

Currently, I'm returning JSON from a single table (using Postgres) with a query like:

```sql
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
  FROM (
    SELECT posts.id, posts.title FROM posts
  ) t
```

Which returns a JSON array like so:

```
[{"id": 1, "title": "what"}]
```

However, I'd like to return JSON from multiple tables in one query so that the final JSON would look something like:

```
{
  "posts": [{"id": 1, "title": "what"}],
  "comments": [{"id": 1, "post_id": 1, "body": "i dunno"}]
}
```

Ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Many. But how do your tables look?

Comment: It is really not clear what you want to do. Do you want to put all records into one array no matter what id oder post_id? array_to_json(array_agg()) can be simplified do json_agg()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know anything about your tables or how your arrays should be created. But if you simply want to aggregate all comments records into one array and all posts into another this could be your code:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=759346b23bf39aa21342b06143a5b6de)

```
SELECT
    json_build_object(
        'posts', (SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(p)) FROM posts p),
        'comments', (SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(c)) FROM comments c)
    )
```

Comment: Perfecto!  Thank you sir.